# how to reload page after take printout using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

below function used for take printout of a div but reloading of page is not working properly after printing(links and jquery ui tabs are not working)

```
    function PrintDiv(id) {           
        var divElements = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;         
        document.body.innerHTML =
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
          divElements + "</body>";
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reloading page` ?

Comment: you can use location.reload(); for reload current page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code:

```
location.reload()
```